# Significant elapsed time differences when calling sort() on different Comparable implementations

Tags: apex, sort, cpu

Before I dive into a bit of code, a summary of my question is: **does anybody know what Salesforce does internally when calling .sort() on a List of custom classes?**

Scenario: I have a wrapper class that contains an Account record and a variable that will be used to sort the list of wrapper objects. My goal here is to sort accounts in a specific way, via some calculation that can't happen in a trigger, formula, validation rule, etc because it relies on user input. For the purpose of this question, my code below just assigns an auto incremented number.

I initially tested this sorting on 3,000 account records. For 3,000 records, the .sort() method was taking around ~3 seconds to run (although the overall CPU time usage was calculated at ~1.5 seconds - *my guess here is that the .sort() method is not counted in the CPU time limit*)

Well, that seemed unacceptable to me. What could I do that would decrease this number? I decided to replace the Account object with an Account ID - if I need to query for more account information later, I'll do it in whatever class needs that information. This makes sense to me - instead of storing an entire Account object in the wrapper class, I'll just store the ID. I doubt this would have much impact on the sorting, but I wanted to see if it made any difference anyway.

**Replacing the Account object with an ID tripled the sort time - on average, it's taking ~9 seconds to now sort the same list of wrapper objects.**

I don't really know why this would be, so any insight here would be appreciated.

I took this a step further and decided to add more properties to the wrapper. It increased the sort time, but only slightly.

**Code**

AccountWrapper.cls:

```
public with sharing class AccountWrapper implements Comparable {
public Account Acct { get; private set; }
public Decimal Score { get; private set; }

public AccountWrapper(Account account, Decimal score) {
    this.Acct = account;
    this.Score = score;
}

public Integer compareTo(Object compareTo) {
    AccountWrapper compareToAccount = (AccountWrapper)compareTo;

    // Reversed the standard logic - I want to order descending
    if (Score < compareToAccount.Score) return 1;
    if (Score > compareToAccount.Score) return -1;
    return 0;
}
}
```

AccountIdWrapper.cls:

```
public with sharing class AccountIdWrapper implements Comparable {
public Id AccountId { get; private set; }
public Decimal Score { get; private set; }

public AccountIdWrapper(Id accountId, Decimal score) {
    this.AccountId = accountId;
    this.Score = score;
}

public Integer compareTo(Object compareTo) {
    AccountIdWrapper compareToAccount = (AccountIdWrapper)compareTo;

    // Reversed the standard logic - I want to order descending
    if (Score < compareToAccount.Score) return 1;
    if (Score > compareToAccount.Score) return -1;
    return 0;
}
}
```

BigWrapper.cls:

```
public with sharing class BigWrapper implements Comparable {
public Id AccountId { get; private set; }
public Id ContactId { get; private set; }
public Id CampaignMemberId { get; private set; }
public Account Acct { get; private set; }
public Decimal Score { get; private set; }

public BigWrapper(Id accountId, Id contactId, Id campaignMemberId, Account account, Decimal score) {
    this.AccountId = accountId;
    this.ContactId = contactId;
    this.CampaignMemberId = campaignMemberId;
    this.Acct = account;
    this.Score = score;
}

public Integer compareTo(Object compareTo) {
    BigWrapper compareToAccount = (BigWrapper)compareTo;

    // Reversed the standard logic - I want to order descending
    if (Score < compareToAccount.Score) return 1;
    if (Score > compareToAccount.Score) return -1;
    return 0;
}
}
```

WrapperTest.cls - I was calling the methods in this class from the dev console for testing:

```
public with sharing class WrapperTest {
public void accountWrapperTest() {
    List<AccountWrapper> accountsToSort = new List<AccountWrapper>();
    List<Account> accounts = [SELECT Id FROM Account];
    for (Integer i = 0, j = accounts.size(); i < j; i++) {
        accountsToSort.add(new AccountWrapper(accounts[i], i));
    }

    Long startTime = DateTime.now().getTime();
    accountsToSort.sort();
    Long stopTime = DateTime.now().getTime();
    System.debug('Elapsed time = ' + (stopTime - startTime));
}

public void accountIdWrapperTest() {
    List<AccountIdWrapper> accountsToSort = new List<AccountIdWrapper>();
    List<Account> accounts = [SELECT Id FROM Account];
    for (Integer i = 0, j = accounts.size(); i < j; i++) {
        accountsToSort.add(new AccountIdWrapper(accounts[i].Id, i));
    }

    Long startTime = DateTime.now().getTime();
    accountsToSort.sort();
    Long stopTime = DateTime.now().getTime();
    System.debug('Elapsed time = ' + (stopTime - startTime));
}

public void bigWrapperTest() {
    List<BigWrapper> accountsToSort = new List<BigWrapper>();
    List<Account> accounts = [SELECT Id FROM Account];
    for (Integer i = 0, j = accounts.size(); i < j; i++) {
        accountsToSort.add(new BigWrapper(accounts[i].Id, null, null, accounts[i], i));
    }

    Long startTime = DateTime.now().getTime();
    accountsToSort.sort();
    Long stopTime = DateTime.now().getTime();
    System.debug('Elapsed time = ' + (stopTime - startTime));
}
}
```

**Sorting Results (~3k account records)**

AccountWrapper.cls - sort() time (ms) / Calculated CPU time (ms)

1. 3333 / 1497
2. 3019 / 1495
3. 3030 / 1527

AccountIdWrapper.cls - sort() time (ms) / Calculated CPU time (ms)
**Note: These are the results that are concerning to me. Why is the sort time so high?**

1. **9856** / 1752
2. **9057** / 2330
3. **9989** / 1804

BigWrapper.cls - sort() time (ms) / Calculated CPU time (ms)

1. 10524 / 1958
2. 10540 / 1974
3. 10827 / 2041

**Apex Profiling Results**

Using AccountWrapper.cls:

> 13:39:50.733 (3733967926)|CUMULATIVE_PROFILING_BEGIN
>
> 13:39:50.733 (3733967926)|CUMULATIVE_PROFILING|SOQL operations|
>   Class.WrapperTest.accountWrapperTest: line 4, column 1: [SELECT Id
>   FROM Account]: executed 1 time in 98 ms
>
> 13:39:50.733 (3733967926)|CUMULATIVE_PROFILING|No profiling
>   information for SOSL operations
>
> 13:39:50.733 (3733967926)|CUMULATIVE_PROFILING|No profiling
>   information for DML operations
>
> 13:39:50.733 (3733967926)|CUMULATIVE_PROFILING|method invocations| External entry point: public static void execute(): executed 1 time in
>   3726 ms
>
> AnonymousBlock: line 2, column 1: public void accountWrapperTest(): executed 1 time in 3725 ms
>
> **Class.WrapperTest.accountWrapperTest: line 10, column 1: global public void sort(): executed 1 time in 2977 ms**
>
> **Class.AccountWrapper.compareTo: line 14, column 1: public Decimal
>   __sfdc_Score(): executed 64659 times in 806 ms**
>
> **Class.WrapperTest.accountWrapperTest: line 6, column 1: public
>   AccountWrapper(Account, Decimal): executed 6026 times in 438 ms**
>
> Class.AccountWrapper.: line 6, column 1: private void
>   __sfdc_Acct(Account): executed 3013 times in 112 ms
>
> Class.AccountWrapper.: line 7, column 1: private void
>   __sfdc_Score(Decimal): executed 3013 times in 78 ms
>
> AnonymousBlock: line 1, column 1: global WrapperTest(): executed 1
>   time in 0 ms
>
> Class.WrapperTest.accountWrapperTest: line 3, column 1: global public
>   List(): executed 1 time in 0 ms
>
> Class.WrapperTest.accountWrapperTest: line 5, column 1: global public
>   Integer size(): executed 1 time in 0 ms
>
> Class.WrapperTest.accountWrapperTest: line 9, column 1: public static
>   Datetime now(): executed 2 times in 0 ms
>
> 13:39:50.733 (3733967926)|CUMULATIVE_PROFILING_END

Using AccountIdWrapper.cls:

> 13:40:13.945 (13945594268)|CUMULATIVE_PROFILING_BEGIN
>
> 13:40:13.945 (13945594268)|CUMULATIVE_PROFILING|SOQL operations|
>   Class.WrapperTest.accountIdWrapperTest: line 17, column 1: [SELECT Id
>   FROM Account]: executed 1 time in 173 ms
>
> 13:40:13.945 (13945594268)|CUMULATIVE_PROFILING|No profiling
>   information for SOSL operations
>
> 13:40:13.945 (13945594268)|CUMULATIVE_PROFILING|No profiling
>   information for DML operations
>
> 13:40:13.945 (13945594268)|CUMULATIVE_PROFILING|method invocations| External entry point: public static void execute(): executed 1 time in
>   13938 ms
>
> AnonymousBlock: line 3, column 1: public void accountIdWrapperTest(): executed 1 time in 13936 ms
>
> **Class.WrapperTest.accountIdWrapperTest: line 23, column 1: global public void sort(): executed 1 time in 12510 ms**
>
> **Class.AccountIdWrapper.compareTo: line 14, column 1: public Decimal
>   __sfdc_Score(): executed 64659 times in 3752 ms**
>
> **Class.WrapperTest.accountIdWrapperTest: line 19, column 1: public
>   AccountIdWrapper(Id, Decimal): executed 6026 times in 1000 ms**
>
> Class.AccountIdWrapper.: line 6, column 1: private void
>   __sfdc_AccountId(Id): executed 3013 times in 357 ms
>
> Class.AccountIdWrapper.: line 7, column 1: private void
>   __sfdc_Score(Decimal): executed 3013 times in 251 ms
>
> AnonymousBlock: line 1, column 1: global WrapperTest(): executed 1
>   time in 0 ms
>
> Class.WrapperTest.accountIdWrapperTest: line 16, column 1: global
>   public List(): executed 1 time in 0 ms
>
> Class.WrapperTest.accountIdWrapperTest: line 18, column 1: global
>   public Integer size(): executed 1 time in 0 ms
>
> Class.WrapperTest.accountIdWrapperTest: line 22, column 1: public
>   static Datetime now(): executed 2 times in 0 ms
>
> 13:40:13.945 (13945594268)|CUMULATIVE_PROFILING_END

Comment: Can you explain the discrepancy between the two posted times? I don't follow what they represent.

Comment: I highlighted the sort() elapsed times for the AccountIdWrapper.cls - these are the ones that are most concerning to me. I posted the calculated CPU times as well, but I realize now this isn't really a CPU time issue. I just don't understand how the sort() time could have jumped from 3 seconds to 9 seconds.

Comment: But, what do you mean by calculated CPU time? Isn't that what the first number represents?

Comment: The first number represents the elapsed time from before and after the .sort() method call. The second number represents the total CPU time used, as reported to me by Salesforce in the debug logs.

Comment: @RobertWatson Can you turn profiling on to the max and post the result of those logs?

Comment: @sfdcfox Thanks, I learned something new today! I've posted up the results into the original thread. I've bolded the code that is running the longest. The compareTo() method jumped from 806ms to 3752ms, but it looks like internal Salesforce code increased much more? Unless I'm not reading it correctly.

Comment: Updating the code I bolded - I bolded the wrong things.

Comment: @RobertWatson That is insightful, isn't it? I'll see if I can make sense of the results.

Comment: What happens if you change the Score from being a Property to a Member? Then access the score member in the sort implementation. The act of increasing the logging may also be blowing out the execution time when using a property.

Comment: An observation about the WrapperTest code. It creates the records to be sorted in an ascending order, and you are reversing them, correct? You might like to randomize them in some tests to get closer to real world sorting than potentially worse case.

Comment: @DanielBallinger Great thoughts! Changing the Score from being a property to a member does improve performance - from ~3s down to ~2s when using the AccountWrapper.cls and from ~9s down to ~6s when using the AccountIdWrapper.cls. Changing the Acct / AccountID to members did *not* have any noticeable effect. So, the original problem still remains: why does storing an ID instead of an Account record cause elapsed time to triple (now from 2s to 6s). (But kudo's for the suggestion - that is definitely something worth remembering) I'm off to play around with the logging levels and sort order next.

Comment: @DanielBallinger The logging was the culprit. I didn't realize how much of an impact it had, but it was completely destroying my results. Re-testing with basic logging produces far better and more consistent results. I'm a bit of an idiot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All, I'm sorry to have wrapped everyone's minds around this today. It was definitely Apex logging levels that was corrupting my results, and now I feel slightly dumb and ever slightly more educated. With very little logging enabled (just enough to debug results & profiling), results are now very consistently the same across all implementations.

Thanks to @DanielBallinger for suggesting I look at logging levels.

Lesson learned: logging levels **greatly** impact performance of Apex code, and in some ways more drastically than you might suspect. (The fact that execution time tripled when storing an ID vs. storing an Account record is still a bit perplexing.)

Comment: In that case, one possible reason that the AccountID might be slower than the account is how it appears in the logs.
For accounts: 6:33:33:352 VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT [11]|this|{"Acct":"0x741aefd6"
For account ID: 16:34:25:953 VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT [11]|compareTo|{"AccountId":"0013600000Pb5sDAAR"}

Comment: That totally makes sense. I once logged a defect because an update of 10 records was getting CPU timeout in an org I was in, then I realized that the debug logs were set to maximum.

Answer (score 1):

Salesforce (presumably) uses the standard [mergesort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort) that's in Java. This means that performance will be O(n) (roughly linear progression of execution time compared to number of elements). I did some experiments in Apex Code, and I've shown that 1000 elements sorted required 999 compareTo calls.

The problem that you have is that you're using an inefficient comparison. Each line of code that you introduce makes the system run slower. For example, you should get much better performance if you do this:

```
public Integer compareTo(Object compareTo) {
    return Score - ((BigWrapper)compareTo).Score;
}
```

Comment: But why would having the member be `Id` type instead of `Account` type slow it down? If anything, it seems like that should be faster.

Comment: @AdrianLarson The code I wrote that contains three elements and sorts by a number runs in ~65ms for 10k rows. I suspect that the difference has to do with the complexity of the compareTo function. The algorithm is supposed to scale linearly, and it does indeed scale linearly in all the tests I've performed.

Comment: @sfdcfox If the compareTo function is the exact same in both AccountWrapper.cls and AccountIdWrapper.cls, and both lists that we're sorting are the same data, how does that make sense?

Comment: @RobertWatson There's something seriously amiss, I think. I can sort 10k records in less than 1/5th of a second, so it seems odd that only 3k records would take 9 seconds. You might try raising a case with support to see if there's something wrong with your instance. I basically re-wrote your code in my org and couldn't come up with 9 seconds of execution time.

Comment: @RobertWatson Just saw your answer. Looks like you found the drawback to debug logs.

Comment: @sfdcfox Indeed. Thanks for your help though, it's definitely something I should have learned ~4 years ago. I guess I just haven't looked at execution time this closely before.